# LDAP connections pooling with kerberos authentication

Tags: java, caching, ldap, kerberos, pooling

The problem I am trying to solve is that when connecting with `LDAP` using kerberos, we request a new `TGT` and session key every time. This puts unnecessary load on the the `KDC` and on the network.

We want to either use a `LDAP` connection pool BUT WITH CUSTOM authentication or somehow just reuse the `TGT`.

Please assist.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches to this:

1. If you don't intend to pool connections, use `LoginContext` to obtain a `Subject` with your TGT, hold that TGT in memory for as long as it is valid and wrap it with a acquire/release implementation. As soon as you have your `Subject` wrap the `new InitialDirContext()` call in a `PriviledgedAction` with `Subject#doAs()`.
2. Using a pool (this is what I do in Spring): Adapt the Commons Pool 2 solution [implemented by Spring LDAP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/#pooling). Though, Spring's `ContextSource` does not support SASL `GSSAPI` mechanism. Luckily, you can [use my library](http://dirctxsrc.sourceforge.net/dircontextsource-spring-ldap.html) for that.

Either way, I using both approaches. The first approach works in a custom authenticator/realm and is blazingly fast here. I wonder why your implemention is so slow -- whatever slow means to you.

Comment: Thanks Michael

1) Would u recommend to reuse the Subject itself of just the TGT Kerberos Ticket?

2) Any recommended cache?

3) Is there an elegant way to validate the TGT based on its end date?

4) Do you know waffle? [link](https://waffle.codeplex.com)

Comment: @YoavS 1) Subject only; 2) Commons Pool 2, as I wrote; 3) Not from the to of my head but only with obtaining a service ticket, though this is cheap to do; 4) Yes, they are really delicious.